# If value exists in column A, write corresponding column B row value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

If the *email* in sheet-1 exists in sheet-2, copy the value in sheet-2 *Type* into Sheet-1 *Status* column.

I've filled in the desired Status values.

**Sheet-1**

| Email | Status (formula) |
| --- | --- |
| abc |  |
| xyz | unsubscribe |
| 123 | bounce |

**Sheet-2**

| Email | Type |
| --- | --- |
| xyz | unsubscribe |
| 123 | bounce |
| qrs | bounce |

This formula checks if the email value exists and writes "found" for Status if it does. (This is for row 43)

```
=if(COUNTIF(Sheet-2!A:A, A43)>0,"found","")
```

I'm thinking I need to use lookup? But how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=index(xlookup(A2:A,D:D,E:E,))
```

- *Adjust the formula ranges as per your sheet*

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Worked with =index(xlookup(A2,'Sheet-2'!A:A,'Sheet-2'!B:B,))  (Couldn't make the A2:A range work with separate sheets)

Comment: that would be `xlookup(A2:A,`

Comment: Error: Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in B3.

Comment: the formula works *array-style* so you only need to use it in Cell_B2 to populate the entire Column_B. do not drag the formula into B3, B4 and so on....

Comment: Gotcha! It's because I still had the old copied formulas in the below cells. Deleted those and voila!